# How do I transform array into an object with index signature and class as a type?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have type A, type B and a class called Person. I need to transform array of type A into array of types B and then somehow send it to the class as an input data. I am really stuck and not sure how I do all of this.

Type A and array of this type:

```
type A = Array<[string, number, string]>;
const a: A = [
['Name1', 15, 'City1'],
['Name2', 44, 'City2'],
['Name3', 23, 'City3'],
['Name4', 73, 'City4'],
['Name5', 12, 'City5']
['Name6', 37, 'City6']];
```

Type B:

```
type B = {
[id: string]: Person}
```

Class Person:

```
class Person {
_id: string; // must be unique
age: number;
name: string;
city: string;

constructor(data) {
    if (data == null) {
        console.log("No data presented")
    } else {
        this._id = data._id
        this.age = data.age
        this.name = data.name
        this.city = data.city
    }
}

tellUsAboutYourself() {
    console.log(
        `Person with unique id = ${this._id} says:\n
         Hello! My name is ${this.name}. I was born in ${this.city}, ${this.age} years ago.`
    );
}}
```

I did this:

```
export const b: B[] = a.map(([name,age,city], index) => ({
[index]: new Person(${index}, {name, age, city})}))
```

But now I can't call method of class like this for some reason:

```
for (let person of b) {
         console.log(person.tellUsAboutYourself());
     }
```

Comment: Is this a class [assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69697228/how-to-transform-an-array-of-arrays-into-an-object-with-index-signature/69697353#69697353)?

Comment: If you want them to be instances of Person, you will need to call the constructor of Person with the `new` keyword (instead of assigning an object that has a similar shape to the class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this example:

```js
type Params = [name: string, age: number, city: string]

type A = Array<Params>;

type B = {
  [id: string]: Person
}

class Person {
  constructor(
    public _id: string,
    public name: string,
    public age: number,
    public city: string
  ) { }

}

const a: A = [
  ['Name1', 15, 'City1'],
  ['Name2', 44, 'City2'],
  ['Name3', 23, 'City3'],
  ['Name4', 73, 'City4'],
  ['Name5', 12, 'City5'],
  ['Name6', 37, 'City6']
];



export const b: B[] = a.map((elem, index) => ({
  [index]: new Person(`${index}`, ...elem)
}))
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgJzgWwM5QLxQNoDsUQBcUqwCAlrgOYA0UcVRUuArsgEYQJ0DG5oxUhWoBdAFBjQkKAEFMshEhAAeeEjQA+ANwSp0AELyA3mKg5yAE0FlKVEcRhdUAe1xiAvhJ4AbOKnSOCC64UCZmPK5CLDzAzggAFKZmUGAs7N7kPFAA+pbWwrRJZqnpmcwE+bY0RSlpGVkMTKwcXNXJtaVZfAIkNtRJAJShUJ4eXpHA9MRyWNhJ2ADkAHIEAIwLdKsArHQLAML8IOsibTjLBABMG1AALDe7B6BXJ-PnyBAAzNcXHw+HXy8zIsVu8btcAOy-KD7Q5gwFnEEQLbXVYXP6gZHw4EEABs1w+4PRIDx4hEOgkYggAA8wHFJhFcKQoOxiPpsCJ5HAAHTIOBgeLxCDeCDIOiUCzUoYYDRQeJhcy4CVU+zMCAAd1gTlc8QABgASIzi6nuHV0LnmoUigYeAYDIA)

You just need to preserve order of `Params` elems in `Person` constructor arguments.